# Using servicestack with MVC3, not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, servicestack

I just created a new MVC3 project and installed servicestack mvc via nuget. I then added this to RegisterRoutes in Global.asax.cs, as per the README.txt:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}"); 
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" }); //Prevent exceptions for favicon
```

Servicestack gives this error:

```
    The resource cannot be found.

    Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

unless I comment out this in Global.asax.cs:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

How can I get MVC3 and Servicestack to work. I'm using VS2010, IIS7.

Comment: Did you install ServiceStack.Host.Mvc? and your Web.config is definitely got ServiceStack mounted at /api route? (this should be done by NuGet install). What url is giving you the 404?

Comment: @mythz Apologies, I didn't realise you had posted a comment. Yes, I think the Web.config is correct. localhost:28945/api is giving 404 when the line I mentioned previously is not commented out. I've uploaded an example project to illustrate the issue: dl.dropbox.com/u/49815808/StackOverflow/Test2.zip

Comment: @Michael - not totally sure, but looking at your IgnoreRoute above, you might need the trailing slash before the route is ignored. Try http://localhost:28945/api/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do these two steps:

1.Disable MVC WebApi registration in Application_Start.

```cs
//WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

2.Ignore MVC route like 'api/'

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: And follow the [MVC Integration wiki!](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration) :)